# Should I prefer $(hostname) over ${HOSTNAME}

Tags: bash, scripting, hostname

So there's the command `hostname` and the environment variable `HOSTNAME` and I'm thinking that the latter is a small savings of a fork & exec in general scripting. On the systems I'm concerned with (Ubuntu) they seem equivalent. It might be different if I were passing one of the flags to `$(hostname)`. Is there an existing consensus on this I'm not aware of?

Comment: Good question; better suited to another forum, however, and already answered there.  http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/28205/7703

Comment: this question belongs on Unix.SE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends how fullproof you want this to be...

environment variables can be altered, and the `HOSTNAME` variable is not read only. The output of the `hostname` command however will always return the latest and most accurate information.

I would personally always use `hostname` command over the environment variable.

Comment: Thanks, I hadn't considered the case of the hostname having changed, IE the machine moving to a different wifi network and dhcp server.